# Google maps markers are changing properties

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drupal, google-maps-markers

I have a map with a lot a marker on it. In my workflow, I take all marker from a filtered list, add them to a `new google.maps.LatLngBounds()` to center my map with the filtered list markers.

It was working fine, but for no reason (on my side), some properties are changed.

At first, I had this :
`coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data.bounds.ab.lo, marker_data.bounds.Fa.lo);`

it stopped working `market_data.bounds.ab is undefined`

so I changed it to

`coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data.bounds.eb.lo, marker_data.bounds.Ha.lo);`

but then `marker_data.bounds.eb`

so this morning I've changed (again) to use Ia and Za. Now my condition looks like this :

```
let coordonnees;
if(marker_data.bounds.ab != null) {
  coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data.bounds.ab.lo, marker_data.bounds.Fa.lo);
} else if(marker_data.bounds.Ia != null && marker_data.bounds.Za != null) {
  coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data.bounds.Za.lo, marker_data.bounds.Ia.lo);
} else {
  coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data.bounds.eb.lo, marker_data.bounds.Ha.lo);
}
```

Why is some properties changing all by themself ?

I'm using GeoField/drupal to generate the marker, but it doesn't seem to come from here.

EDIT :

Found a solution by doing this, but still can't explain why the properties are changed

```
let latitudeKey = Object.keys(marker_data.bounds)[0]
let latitude = marker_data.bounds[latitudeKey].lo

let longitudeKey = Object.keys(marker_data.bounds).pop()
let longitude = marker_data.bounds[longitudeKey].lo
coordonnees = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Why is some properties changing all by itself ?*

Because you are not using documented methods. The API is [fully documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). Do **not** use undocumented properties as these can change at any time.

The [`LatLng` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) has methods available, such as `lat()` and `lng()`.

And the same goes for the [`LatLngBounds` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds).

For example, if you were to find the latitude of the south-west corner of a `LatLntBounds` object, you can do:

```
let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
// Do stuff with your bounds object here then
let swLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
```

As you can see from the docs, `getSouthWest()` method returns a `LatLng` object, which has a `lat()` method.